# Host MVC application inside Drupal application in IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal website and an MVC site. I want to host the MVC site as a Web application inside Drupal website in IIS.Overall my IIS configuration looks as below:

[image]

The URL of the main test is https://mysite.orgg/ and I want the URL of the MVC application to be https://mysite.orgg/mymvc/home/login. When I set the IIS like this and try to browse the URL for the MVC application, I see 'Page not found' error from Drupal site. Is there any way that this can be fixed?

Comment: could you please share the detailed error message? did you get an error on all the pages? make sure in iis request filtering  Allow unlisted file name extensions is checked IIS your site → request Filtering → Filename Extensions Tab → Edit Feature Settings → Allow unlisted filename extensions. and in  Web.Config
`<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >      
    </modules>`

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have to adjust drupal's `.htaccess` (located inside `web` dir) file that catches requests and forwards them to index.php.

There you would have to i.e. add extra condition like:

```
RewriteRule ^(mymvc) - [L]
```

... which would exclude your mvc path. My best guess is to add it here:

```
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Didn't try it, but that's the basic idea.